# Bios can't see Sandisk Dual ultra on USB 3.0

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, lenovo, bios

I'm using Lenovo g70-80, that include USB port 3.0, and my Sandisk Ultra 64G boot perfectly from this port, but when I'd tried to boot any OS from Sandisk Dual Ultra 250G. that should be able to connect even to USB 3.1, couldn't being detected on my bios, and I'd tried to turn off and on the secure boot, with no results. I'd tried to change to pure UEFI and to Legancy Support, but no helpful results. The USB just didn't got detected by the bios. Update the bios and other things of lenovo, and update intel drivers and NVIDIA drivers didn't help.
May I should say that the Sandisk Ultra 64G still working properly, but it's very old and slow, and don't have that much space for OS.
Someone in the past told me that might my PC is too old and can't detect USB devices that usign USB 3.1, but I don't think so, because I still can use it from any OS I'd tried- Windows, tons of linux distros, and they could detect it properly, and to transfer file or installing on this any type of OS I'd tried, (even win-to-go, after hard work).
I probably should mention that the bios **COULD** detect it from USB 2.0 port.

Thanx for help.
Shukketsuki.

Comment: Sounds like it is a USB 2 device and you need to treat it as such.

Comment: No, it isn't. I bought it for using 250G on USB 3.0, but I found only USB 3.1.